Text match filter gives unknown operator error
I have PostgreSQL database with Llamaindex and I am doing filter search over it. Many operators work but text match filter doesn't work. I have newest version of Llamaindex.
It gives this error:

Unknown operator: FilterOperator.TEXT_MATCH, fallback to '='

My code:
filters = MetadataFilters(
    filters=[
        MetadataFilter(key="title",
        operator=FilterOperator.TEXT_MATCH,
        value="Graph RAG")
    ]
)

Alternatively:
operator="text_match"
Rest of code.
